# clockwise and then anticlockwise rotation in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to rotate a canvas element to first do animation of rotation in clockwise direction by 180 degree then do a reverse(anticlockwise) rotation of 180 degree.I have used this code but its not working as i want.

```js
 function Rotate(arg) {
                rotateInterval = setInterval(function () {
                    arg.save(); //saves the state of canvas
                    arg.clearRect(0, 0, arg.canvas.width, arg.canvas.height); //clear the canvas
                    arg.translate(arg.canvas.width / 2, arg.canvas.height / 2); //let's translate

                    if (flag2 == false)
                       arg.rotate(-(ang += 5) * Math.PI / 180); //increment the angle and rotate the image 
                        //arg.style.rotate(5);
                    else {
                        
                        ang = 0;
                        arg.rotate((ang += 5) * Math.PI / 180);
                       
                    }
                    if (ang == 180) {
                        if (flag2 == true)
                            flag3 = true;
                        else
                        flag2 = true;
                    }
                    if (flag3 == true && ang == 180) {
                        clearInterval(rotateInterval)
                        flag2 = false;
                    }
                    // ctxOne.drawImage(bowl, -ctxOne.canvas.width / 2, -ctxOne.canvas.height / 2, ctxOne.canvas.width, ctxOne.canvas.height); //draw the image ;)
                    arg.drawImage(bowl, -90, -90, 180, 180);
                    arg.restore(); //restore the state of canvas
                }, 100);
            }
```

Comment: You set `flag2` always `true`. Change `if (ang = 180)` ---> `if (ang == 180)`. And then tell us more exactly **what** goes wrong (*not working as I want* is a bit unclear).

Comment: i have edited the code and made it correct. Now arg context rotates 180 degree anticlockwise smoothly (animated) but then clockwise rotation is not performed in animation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have introduced a `flag3` but I think you don't need it. I assume that rotation starts with `ang = 0` and `flag2` shall tell the rotation direction: increment when false and decrement when true. But you always set `ang = 0` when it is true. Your code should look like:

```
var rotateInterval, ang = 0, flag2 = false;

function Rotate(arg) {

rotateInterval = setInterval(function () {
    arg.save();
    arg.clearRect(0, 0, arg.canvas.width, arg.canvas.height);
    arg.translate(arg.canvas.width / 2, arg.canvas.height / 2);

    if (flag2 == false) ang += 5; // increment ang if flag2 == false ( = go forward)
    else ang -= 5; // otherwise decrement ang ( = go backwards)

    arg.rotate(ang * Math.PI / 180); // set the new ang to the rotation

    if (ang == 180) flag2 = true; // change direction if 180 deg is reached

    if (flag2 == true && ang == 0) { // if we go backwards and have reached 0 reset
        clearInterval(rotateInterval)
        flag2 = false;
    }

    arg.drawImage(bowl, -90, -90, 180, 180);
    arg.restore(); //restore the state of canvas
}, 100);

}
```

Now the angle starts with 0, goes stepwise up to 180, then stepwise back to 0, then stops.

Comment: what to do if i don't want to translate the 'arg' canvas element during rotation?

Comment: @MayankChaturvedi Then just remove the line `arg.translate(arg.canvas.width / 2, arg.canvas.height / 2);`

Comment: Then the image is rotating out of the canvas, but on changing coordinates in drawImage, the problem is that rotation is around the pivot, upper left corner of canvas.I want to shift the pivot to center of the image without translating it.How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Does rotate() rotate an element relative to its current transformation or is it an absolute rotation? Instead of doing

```
    (angle+=5)*Math.PI / 180
```

try

```
    5*Math.PI / 180
```

for your rotate argument. That way rotate will rotate it by an addition 5 degrees every time. And make it -5 when it's going backwards. I guess at that point you'd use a counter to determine if 180/5 steps have passed and make it time to go backwards.